# CSS media queries not displaying screen sizes correctly

Tags: css

I am currently trying to design a layout which will work for multiple screen sizes. The screen sizes are listed below:

640x960
768x1280
1024x768
1366x768
1280x800
1366x768
1280x1024

Based on the screen sizes, I want the box content height to fit within the screen size, so that there is no vertical scrollbar for a smaller window or any window sizes.

I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly for the box, the height doesnt seem to adjust correctly based on the media queires, which is causeing the vertical scrollbar to show up; can someone show how this can be fixed?

```
@media only screen and (min-width:640px) and (max-height:960px){
    .grid {
        height: 402px;     
        background:#ff3333;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-height:1280px) {
    .grid {
        height: 612px;     
        background:#33ff33;
        border:11px solid #33ff33 !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-height:768px){
    .grid {
        height: 302px;     
        background: #55aaff;
        border:11px solid #55aaff !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1366px) and (max-height:768px){
    .grid {
        height: 329px;     
        background:#cccccc;
        border:11px solid #000000 !important;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1280px) and (max-height:800px){
        .grid {
            height: 539px;     
            background:#cccccc;
            border:11px solid pink !important;
        }
}    

 @media only screen and (min-width:1280px) and (max-height:1024){
                .gridStyle {
                    height: 539px;     
                    background:#cccccc;
                    border:11px solid yellow !important;
                }
 }
```

Comment: Now that your indentation has been fixed, you can see you seem to have left out several closing brackets for your last several media queries (not including the last one)

Comment: Did you fix the closing brackets as @TylerH suggested?

Comment: @joe -yes i have updaed the code.. still showing veritcal scrollbar.

Comment: Are you accounting for the additional 22px being added to the height from the border? Also you have `(min-width:1366px) and (max-height:768px)` twice, each with different values for gridStyle's height

Answer (score 1):

Any reason for not wanting a vertical scrollbar?
You can just write a width based media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {

}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

}
```

etc, and then use `overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: @antonia- Thnks, i dont want to hide or cut of the box, i dont want the user to scroll vertically to view the content. everything should fit within the various screen sizes.